# How to say "From /a book/?"

Tags: particles

So recently I was commenting about how a song was related to a book, and I said that there were names of certain characters in the song. Then I wanted to say that when I looked up the names, I found out that they were from the book, The Plague. But I couldn't figure out how you would say that. I ended up doing this:

「ペスト」のキャラクターを見つけ出します！

So how would you say "from /a book/?" Using from in that way seems like a particular English expression. Is there an equivalent one in Japanese? Or can I just use に? "「ペスト」に" made the most sense to me, but then how would I use that with を, for 見つけ出します?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could say:

> 「[Actual Name(s)]  は小説{しょうせつ}『ペスト』から来{き}ていることがわかった。」

or

> 「[Actual Name(s)]  は小説『ペスト』の登場人物{とうじょうじんぶつ}の名前{なまえ}であることがわかった。」

The first sentence is more informal in word choices and structure.

Your sentence:

> 「『ペスト』のキャラクターを見つけ出します！」

makes little sense.  At least it does not mean what you want to say this time.

「見つけ出します！」 can only mean "**I'm going to find ~~!**" when, in reality,  you have already found something.  It talks about near future, not immediate past.

While I would not call your word choice of 「キャラクター」 incorrect, 「登場人物」 would be a way more common word for this.

Answer (score 1):

**I made a big mistake in the original answer.** I'll show you an edited answer.

**【Original】**

> - 「The Plague」という名前は、本で見つけました。
> - 「The Plague」って、（私が読んでいる「＊＊＊＊」）という本で見つけたの。
> - 「The Plague」の出典は「＊＊＊＊」という本です。
>
> 最初の２つの文は、主語がIで、過去の事実を述べているので過去形で書くのが普通です。
>   「ペスト」のキャラクターを見つけ出します！
>   →「ペスト」のキャラクターを見つけました! または、「ペスト」のキャラクターを見つけた！

**【Edited】**

> 「ペスト」のキャラクターを見つけ出します！

- 「ペスト」という題名{だいめい}の本{ほん}でキャラクターの名前{なまえ}を見{み}つけました！
- 「ペスト」っていう本に載{の}ってたよ！
- キャラクターの名前{なまえ}、「ペスト」からなんだ！

It is natural for you to write the first two sentences in a **past tense** because they are the past facts that you did or experienced by yourself. However, I recommend you to write the last sentence in a **present tense** because it tells only a fact not having to do with you.

【**Additional information and an illustration**】

I considered to make it clear how prepositions に, で and から should be properly used in a Japanese sentence which has the same meaning of English "**I found the names of the characters from the book, The Plague**."

I'll show you the consideration by the **illustration** drawn below.

In conclusion, the following sentences are acceptable:

- 私は「＊＊＊」という登場人物（＝キャラクター）の名前を「ペスト」という題名の本（/本の中）で見つけました。
- 私は「＊＊＊」という登場人物（＝キャラクター）の名前が「ペスト」という題名の本（/本の中）にあることを見つけました。
- 私は「＊＊＊」という登場人物（＝キャラクター）の名前が「ペスト」という題名の本からだということを見つけました。

[image]

Comment: `「The Plague」という名前は、本で見つけました。...「The Plague」の出典は「＊＊＊＊」という本です。` >> "[The Plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Plague) (「[ペスト](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9A%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88_(%E5%B0%8F%E8%AA%AC))」)" は、キャラクターの名前ではなく、歌に出てくるキャラクターたちが登場する本（小説）の題名だと思うのですが。。。

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just to clarify, going from your answers,  as prepositions go, に, で, から can all be used to mean "from" in that sense, に and で depending on the verb and から more generally? (Sorry that this is so long after your answer!)

Comment: @Smoothie >に and で depending on the verb and から more generally?  Give me a time. I will show the answer later on.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check this for a while! I know I'm not supposed to leave a comment just thanking you but... wow, this is very complete! Thank you for the diagram and clarifying!